# Can react native apps be displayed in a browser

Tags: c#, xamarin, react-native

I have a windows c# application for which I have previously developed a web client (HTML/JS) which accesses the shared data through an oData REST service.

I am now looking to move the entire application to a single platform across all devices. This will be native to iOS and Android, but I am looking to share code as much as possible. I am not interested in hybrid apps.

The two viable options are Xamarin and React Native. Although I hate Javascript, I am leaning towards React, simply because of momentum - the xamarin team seems to be very small and there is not a lot of evidence of extensive support for the xamarin platform from within microsoft.

My concern with React is - although it seems that it will get the job done on iOS and Android, it is not clear how you can run applications on PC/Mac. I am aware there is UWP / WPF support but am unsure if this is of any quality. I expect the best solution would be to run it in a browser on non-mobile platforms.

Is this possible with React Native, and is it something you could use in production in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Not to say you shouldn't consider React, but your opinions regarding Xamarin is not correct. For example, you can submit the bug in their system and you'll get the answer usually in a day, without paying anything. If you pay you'll get answers even faster. I am not sure if they have a lot of people or just few of them, but I haven't seen any single company/product that responsive. For some products like Mac I can see that my requests were fixed in a few days (sure not in a release version but on their system).

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I am leaning towards staying on the Xamarin path at the moment - at least to do the quick and dirty part of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft ReactXP](https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp) is exactly what you are looking for.

Although it is still very young (first release at 22 Apr, 2017), [Nader Dabit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864119/nader-dabit) did some really excellent works on it.

[Video Tutorial Here](https://medium.com/@dabit3/reactxp-first-look-d3dd1d08febd)

Comment: Thanks Val - it appears that this does do as the question asked - although I would want this to be a bit more mature before I put more faith in it. Also, it upports UWP which is handy - but only with a status of "in progress" whatever that means.