# can we develop a web-based application with same code base using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native I want to know can we able to share the same code base for web-based and for the mobile application using react native.

If yes then how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can react native apps be displayed in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454542/can-react-native-apps-be-displayed-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to using React to build a web application and then wondering if you can port it to React-Native? You can share the same idea's, method, and architecture. But no, the code doesn't translate 100%, really not even 50%. React vs React-Native use different things, for example React uses < Div >'s while React-Native uses < View >'s, img to < Image >, etc. So while figuring out many of the design questions and implementation for the web version will surely make your RN development faster. You still need to plan on the RN port being the same Development process (plus longer for bug testing on the many different devices) and allow a developer adequate time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. You can share the same code using [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

But keep in mind that the idea behind React and React Native projects is that you could **learn one time and use everywhere** so their goal is to make possible to use a very similar architecture, data flow, etc. but not sharing the same code. Also, a lot of packages and third-party components will not work as expected. So, [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) is a very interesting project and you should definitely give it a chance, but most of the times it will not do the job 100%.